DDPG Not Learning
I'm looking for some help related to my DDPG implementation. My code runs and correctly learns the pendulum gymnasium environment however trying it on any other environment has not worked. I've left it running for 6000 episodes of 700 steps. I even tried 12000 episodes on bipedalwalker. I'm not sure if my code logic is the problem or if it just needs to run longer. Any help is appreciated and let me know if there is a better place to ask this kind of question.
class OUNoise:
def __init__(self,size,mu=0,theta=.15,sigma=.2):
    self.size=size
    self.mu=mu*np.ones(size)
    self.theta=theta
    self.sigma=sigma
    self.state=self.mu.copy()
def reset(self):
    self.state=self.mu.copy()
def noise(self):
    x=self.state
    dx=self.theta*(self.mu-x)+self.sigma*np.random.randn(len(x))
    self.state=x+dx
    return self.state
class ReplayBuffer:
def __init__(self,memory_capacity=100000,batch_size=256,num_actions=4,num_states=24):
    self.memory_capacity=memory_capacity
    self.num_states=num_states
    self.num_actions=num_actions
    self.batch_size=batch_size
    self.buffer_counter=0
    self.state_buffer=np.zeros((self.memory_capacity,self.num_states))
    self.action_buffer=np.zeros((self.memory_capacity,self.num_actions))
    self.reward_buffer=np.zeros(self.memory_capacity)
    self.next_state_buffer=np.zeros((self.memory_capacity,self.num_states))
    self.done_buffer=np.zeros(self.memory_capacity)
def record(self,observation,action,reward,next_observation,done):
    index = self.buffer_counter % self.memory_capacity
    self.state_buffer[index] = observation
    self.action_buffer[index] = action
    self.reward_buffer[index] = reward
    self.next_state_buffer[index] = next_observation
    self.done_buffer[index] = done
    self.buffer_counter += 1

def sample(self):
    range1 = min(self.buffer_counter, self.memory_capacity)
    indices = np.random.randint(0, range1, size=self.batch_size)
    states = torch.tensor(self.state_buffer[indices], dtype=torch.float32)
    actions = torch.tensor(self.action_buffer[indices], dtype=torch.float32)
    rewards = torch.tensor(self.reward_buffer[indices], dtype=torch.float32)
    next_states = torch.tensor(self.next_state_buffer[indices], dtype=torch.float32)
    dones = torch.tensor(self.done_buffer[indices], dtype=torch.float32)
    return states,actions,rewards,next_states,dones

class Critic(nn.Module):
def __init__(self,num_states,num_actions,action_bound,learning_rate):
    super(Critic,self).__init__()
    self.num_actions=num_actions
    self.num_states=num_states
    self.action_bound=action_bound
    
    self.lC=learning_rate
    self.state_fc=nn.Linear(num_states,200)
    self.state_bn=nn.BatchNorm1d(200)
    self.action_fc=nn.Linear(num_actions,200)
    self.action_bn=nn.BatchNorm1d(200)
    self.combined_fc1=nn.Linear(400,400)
    self.combined_bn1=nn.BatchNorm1d(400)
    self.combined_fc2=nn.Linear(400,1)
def forward(self,state,action):
    state_out=F.relu(self.state_fc(state))
    action_out=F.relu(self.action_fc(action))
    combined=torch.cat([state_out,action_out],dim=1)
    combined=F.relu(self.combined_fc1(combined))
    q_value=self.combined_fc2(combined)
    return torch.squeeze(q_value)
class Actor(nn.Module):
def __init__(self,num_states,num_actions,learning_rate,action_bound):
    super(Actor,self).__init__()
    self.num_states=num_states
    self.num_actions=num_actions
    self.lA=learning_rate
    self.action_bound=action_bound
    self.fc1=nn.Linear(num_states,400)
    self.fc1_bn=nn.BatchNorm1d(400)
    self.fc2=nn.Linear(400,300)
    self.fc2_bn=nn.BatchNorm1d(300)
    self.fc3=nn.Linear(300,num_actions)
def forward(self,state):
    out=F.relu(self.fc1(state))
    out=F.relu(self.fc2(out))
    action=torch.tanh(self.fc3(out))*self.action_bound
    return action
class Agent:
def __init__(self,env):
    self.env=env
    self.state_dimension=self.env.observation_space.shape[0]
    print(self.state_dimension)
    self.action_dimension=self.env.action_space.shape[0]
    self.action_bound=float(self.env.action_space.high[0])
    self.buffer=ReplayBuffer()
    self.learning_rate1=.0001
    self.learning_rate2=.001
    self.tau=.005
    self.gamma=.9
    
    self.actor=Actor(self.state_dimension,self.action_dimension,self.learning_rate1,self.action_bound)
    self.critic=Critic(self.state_dimension,self.action_dimension,self.action_bound,self.learning_rate2)
    self.target_actor=Actor(self.state_dimension,self.action_dimension,self.learning_rate1,self.action_bound)
    self.target_critic=Critic(self.state_dimension,self.action_dimension,self.action_bound,self.learning_rate2)
    self.ou_noise=OUNoise(self.action_dimension)

    self.target_actor.load_state_dict(self.actor.state_dict())
    self.target_critic.load_state_dict(self.critic.state_dict())
    self.actor_optimizer=optim.Adam(self.actor.parameters(),lr=self.learning_rate1)
    self.critic_optimizer=optim.Adam(self.critic.parameters(),lr=self.learning_rate2)
def target_network_update(self):
    for target_param, param in zip(self.target_actor.parameters(),self.actor.parameters()):
        target_param.data.copy_(self.tau*param.data+(1-self.tau)*target_param.data)
    for target_param, param in zip(self.target_critic.parameters(),self.critic.parameters()):
        target_param.data.copy_(self.tau*param.data+(1-self.tau)*target_param.data)
def train(self,max_step,max_episode):
    theta_values=[]
    time_values=[]
    invert=[]
    for episode in range(max_episode):
        state,_=self.env.reset()
        for step in range(max_step):
            noise=self.ou_noise.noise()
            action=self.actor(torch.tensor(state,dtype=torch.float32)).detach().numpy()+noise
            action=np.clip(action,-self.action_bound,self.action_bound)
            next_state,reward,done,trunc,info=self.env.step(action)
            reward*=10
            self.buffer.record(state,action,reward,next_state,done)
            states,actions,rewards,next_states,dones=self.buffer.sample()
            states=torch.FloatTensor(states)
            actions=torch.FloatTensor(actions)
            rewards=torch.FloatTensor(rewards)
            next_states=torch.FloatTensor(next_states)
            dones=torch.FloatTensor(dones)
            target_actions=self.target_actor(next_states)
            target_q=self.target_critic(next_states,target_actions)
            targets=rewards+self.gamma*target_q*(1-dones)
            predicted_q=self.critic(states,actions)
            critic_loss=F.mse_loss(targets,predicted_q)
            self.critic_optimizer.zero_grad()
            critic_loss.backward()
            self.critic_optimizer.step()
            actions_pred=self.actor(states)
            q_v=self.critic(states,actions_pred)
            actor_loss=-torch.mean(q_v)
            self.actor_optimizer.zero_grad()
            actor_loss.backward()
            self.actor_optimizer.step()
            self.target_network_update()
            if done:
                break
            print(reward)
            state=next_state

